# How to create a build pipeline for multi-module maven in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, maven, azure-devops, multi-module

I have a multi-module maven project in azure repo:

```
Parent
  ----App
        --POM.xml
  ----Core
        --POM.xml
  ----API
        --POM.xml
  ----ParentPOM.xml
```

When I tried to build **App** project in Azure, I am getting the following error: [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on the project: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.core:jar:1.0: Could not find artifact com.core:jar:1.0 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).

So I tried to create multiple tasks in the same azure build to package for each module **(App, Core, API)**, which also gives the same result. Could someone please help me on how to build the multi-module project and get the **App jar** file.

Answer (score 3):

The way I've done it:

with this command: install -pl (module name) -am

where the module name should be one of the submodules. If you want to build all of them then only go with install

Answer (score -3):

I have found the solution for the multi-module maven dependency issue, First We need to build the parent pom.xml, then build the submodules as per hierarchical order. In between each module, add a task to copy and move the jar files to the staging directory. Here shared the image of my build steps. Please take a look and comment on any questions.

[Please look into the DevOps configuration for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8BlF.png)